How to set up Firebase Dynamic Links
On 2024/4/25 we tried to begin setting up a new Firebase Dynamic Link setting, and noticed the "Get Start" button is missing.
We are unable to add a new domain for Dyanmic Links because the button is missing.
We understand Dynamic Links support will end 2025/8/25. Can we add a new domain until this date?
If it is possible, please tell us how.

Log in to firebase console

2.Display dynamic links page
